# Increase development speed for .NET website

Tags: web-development, tools

I am curious to know that how we can make web site development much faster. I am specific about asp.net.

As far as my knowledge is concern, we can make asp.net website development faster by

Using Log4Net - to capture logging information
Entity framework - to increase database operation speed.

So, is there other tools also which we can use to optimize the development process?

If you have used in any of your project, whether it was a small project or large.

Comment: This belongs on stackoverflow.com and should be a community wiki.

Comment: Can you clarify how this is related to running a web site? This question seems deeply rooted in .net development methodology and continuous integration (which makes it off topic for this site). See the [FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are webforms person, I recommend [.netTiers](http://nettiers.com/). My co-worker raves about it and I've played some with it. It created the models and views dynamically. But, I'm a asp-net-mvc man. I created CodeTemplates for generating custom views, controllers, etc rapidly. Also checkout [MVCContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/).